# Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в конструкции “такими же или ещё более… чем”?

Tags: пунктуация

Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в предложении "Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же(,) или еще более(,) жестокими, чем СС"? Я полагаю, что **такими же** и **более жестокими** - однородные члены, соединенные союзом **или**, так ли это?
Правильно оформленное предложение, по моему мнению, будет выглядеть так:
"Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же или еще более жестокими, чем СС".

Comment: А однородный член зачем разбили (предполагаете разбить)?

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вы предположили, что возможна запятая между "более" и "жесткими". Без этого ваш вопрос смотрится просто дико.

Comment: Я ничего такого не предполагал, для меня знак почти очевиден. Просто видел несколько употреблений таких фраз в учебниках социологии. Оформлялись они так: 
"Они чувстовали гордость, когда им удавалась быть такими же, или еще более,  жестокими, чем СС"
Для меня эта постановка знаков кажется абсурдной и абсолютно неправильной, но кто знает?

Comment: @shampar, я понял, о чем вы. Я, наверное, допустил ошибку, не написав свой вариант, сейчас дополню.

Comment: *Я ничего такого не предполагал, для меня знак почти очевиден.*  - еще не легче. А что ж вы от нас-то хотите, если для вас "пости очевиден" является аргументом?!

Comment: Я хотел уточнить, правильны ли мои знаки препинания. Как тот факт, что они для меня почти очевидны, меняет факт, что мне нужно узнать правильность знаков препинания.  Вы занимаетесь подлогом и демагогией, неправильной интепретацией слов. Вы боритесь с ветряными мельницами, если угодно. Прочитайте сообщение мое и ваше еще раз, попытаясь проанализировать ситуацию. Вы очень бескультурный человек, если считаете, что можете так говорить с людьми. Со всеми(не только со мной) ведете беседу в снисходительно-презрительной манере, всегда докапываетесь к словам вместо ответа на вопросы, это неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь **нет** ошибки! Согласование идёт с последним элементом. Такая ситуация характерна для русского языка.
*Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же [жестокими, как СС,] или еще более(,) жестокими, чем СС.* || Фраза в скобках пропущена и очевидна по смыслу. "Чем СС" грамматически не относится к "такими же".

Вариант с присоединительным оборотом является неудачным стилистически, как бы он не оформлялся, потому что "ещё более" на слух требует "чем", а получает неожиданно "как" (что необходимо по грамматике). Это не звучит:
*Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же, или еще более, жестокими, как СС.

Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же (или еще более жестокими), как СС.* || Основную информацию не следует заключать в скобки, как и делать из неё вставку с двумя тире. Основная — потому что "такими же, как" или "ещё более, чем" можно поменять местами.
*Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же — или еще более—  жестокими, как СС.*

Следующий вариант является некорректным грамматически:
*Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же, или еще более, жестокими, **чем** СС.* || Либо нужно высвобождать от запятых изолированный оборот "или еще более", либо менять "чем" на "как".

Answer (score 0):

В предложении явная ошибка.

**Обособление** допускаем. Тогда ***или ещё более*** - это вставная конструкция, попутное замечание. Вставку всегда можно убрать. Получаем: *Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же ... жестокими, чем СС*. Ошибка явная, ведь нужно ***такими же жестокими, КАК...***

Смысл предложения в этом случае: *Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же жестокими, как СС, или ещё более жестокими, чем СС.*

Если грамматическую ошибку исправить и признать наличие вставки, то получаем варианты:

***Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же (или еще более) жестокими, как СС.***

***Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же - или еще более -  жестокими, как СС.***  Плюс вариант с запятой.

Произносить вставку при этом нужно с особой интонацией, чтобы было слышно, что это всего лишь попутное замечание.

**Если же вставки нет,** а *такими же или ещё более жестокими* - это однородные члены, то перед *или* всё равно нужен разграничитель. Почему? Смысл высказывания уже другой, выразим его пока в двух предложениях: ***Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же.*** И: ***Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть ещё более жестокими, чем СС.***

***Они чувствовали гордость, когда им удавалось быть такими же - или еще более жестокими, чем СС.*** В этом случае  благодаря тире появляется нужная интонация, и всё становится на свои места. Вот такая особая функция у тире в данном случае.

Простите, если я не  права. Это всего лишь мои размышления по  поводу.

Comment: Я тоже думал, что это присоединительный оборот, однако меня переубедили, когда я задал вопрос на  другом форуме, привели они такие предложения:


Этнография не знает ни одного отсталого народа, будь он таким же или еще более первобытным, чем, скажем, австралийцы или огнеземельцы прошлого века, который не имел бы своего звукового языка;






Мы видим, что незабвенный автор Славянских Древностей превращению Финских Болгар в Славян находит аналогию в таком же или еще более быстром превращении Скандинавской Руси тоже в Славян.
Даже не знаю...

Comment: Как хорошо, что Вы приводите эти примеры! Второй вполне приемлем, в нём нет ошибки такого рода. А вот в первом есть. Точно такая же.

Comment: Да, все верно, во втором такой же ошибки нет, вы правы.  Возможно, следует задать вопрос справочной службе русского языка на сайте грамоты.ру и посмотреть, что они скажут. Я задумывался до вашего ответа над таким же, как и у вас, объяснением, однако спросить-то не у кого, остается лишь догадываться)